# Issue to import python libraries/moduls for a ROS2 subscriber

Tags: python, ros2, subscriber

I am new to use ROS in my project. I have installed ROS2 humble on Ubuntu 22.04. I need to import different python codes/functions as modules to a ROS2 subscriber (python code).

They are:

1. `common_utils.py`  in `utils` folder
2. `build_network` which is a function in `pointpillar.py`.

Both python codes are located in another folder which is not a ROS2 package (`home/user/Machine_Learning`) and its directory is different from subscriber directory (`home/user/DL_ws/src/object_detection/object_detection/pc_subscriber.py`).

In my subscriber code, I changed the directory to `Machine_Learning` folder, then I used `from utils import common_utils` and `from pointpillar import build_network`.

With/without updating `package.xml` (adding `utils` and `pointpillar` for `</exec_depend>`), then `colcon build`, when I use `ros2 run object_detection listener`, I get this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'` or `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pointpillar'`.

How can I solve this issue?

I appreciate any help in advance.

Thanks, Abbas

Answer (score 0):

You can append path of the python code/modules to system paths:

```
import sys

extra_path = '/home/user/Machine_Learning' # path to folder with python code to import
sys.path.append(extra_path)

from utils import common_utils
from pointpillar import build_network
```

`extra_path` can be either absolute or relative path to the code directory.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your suggestion. I used it, but it shows me another error. Let assume there is a sub-folder (augmenter) in utils folder which includes "data_augmentor.py". I have "from .augmentor.data_augmentor import DataAugmentor" in "common_utils.py". After trying your suggestion, I got this error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data.augmentor'". Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: this seems like an import error within the extra python code itself. can you first make sure that your python code works on its own by writing a test script in extra_path that imports the same as above. i would also recomment avoid using relative imports if possible, e.g. instead of `from .augmentor.data_augmentor`, use `from utils.augmentor.data_augmentor`

You can also share your directory structure for better understanding.

Comment: Actually, I am using lots of python codes for point cloud object detection using pointpillar.  The codes are in different folders and sub-folders. I have already trained and tested the deep learning method and it worked. I am trying to apply these codes with the same structure in ROS2 subscriber package. I think `from utils.augmentor.data_augmentor` does not work, since utils does not have another sub-folder named utils.